# Recommend any tool to place .docx files on website for viewing so that search engines crawl it?

Tags: web-crawlers

Recommend any tool to place .docx files on website for viewing so that search engines crawl it without any problem.

I use scribd viewer, set the document as private on scribd and embed the file on my website through iframe but Google isn't listing keywords for the content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upload your docx file on your webserver. Then you can embed it using office web app viewer or Google docs viewer. Don't forget to add that file in sitemap. Google will crawl it.

https://docs.google.com/viewer

Comment: Thank you very much. I just applied your stated method. But I want to ask another question. I just give the website url to generate sitemap, and that lists the page containing .docx file too. What else can I do in generating sitemaps, so that google will surely crawl and generate content keywords of the .dox file ?

Comment: Either you can add url in sitemap or you can add page that containing sitemap. All will work same. Google bots are intelligent. Even if they find any link from any page of your website or from other website they will crawl it.